# How to create given specific pivot table in R?

Tags: r, pivot, pivot-table, reshape, reshape2

I have a requirement of creating pivot table from dataframe given below :

[image]

Kindly help me to get pivot table as given below (I have copied from excel) :

[image]

I need exactly given as using R.

To generate the similar set of dataset you can use the command given below :

```
enter code here

Data1 <- data.frame(
X = sample(1:10),
Y = sample(1:10), 
Z = sample(1:10),
count= sample(11:20))
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you provide a working example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Here, is the code, using it you can create the similar dataframe which i have described above :

Data1 <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(1:10), 
  Z = sample(1:10),
  count= sample(11:20))

Comment: The package `reshape` could be useful in most of the pivots.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ftable`:

```
exData <- setNames(as.data.frame(unique(t(combn(rep(1:3, 3), m=3)))), paste0("P", 1:3))
ftable(exData)
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, i can able to create the pivot table using ftable function, though i didn't understand the logic used in while saving dataframe in exData. can you please explain the same? Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Can you expand your answer by elaborating each step?